# azure re-run startup task in cloud service without restarting role

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, phantomjs, azure-cloud-services

I have an azure cloud service startup tasks that creates a PhantomJS process which hosts a web server in the background.  Sometimes the PhantomJS processes needs to be restarted.

How would I re-run this startup task without having to a do a full role recycle?

I have an endpoint that I hit every 5 minutes to check the status of the PhantomJS process and if it comes back as a failure, I want to restart this process.

I'd prefer to stay away from using Process.Start within asp.net as then I have to worry about credentials and user impersonation to start the process back up.

My startup tasks runs the following...

START /B  "my_log.txt >>" /D "%~dp0" phantomjs2.exe --local-to-remote-url-access=true --ignore-ssl-errors=true js\renderHtmlWebServer.js >>  "%TEMP%\PhantomJS_%datetimef%.txt" 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

You can't rerun your startup task without restarting the role, but you could move that code into your Run method in WebRole.cs.  The run method runs in WaIISHost.exe (or WaWorkerHost.exe for a worker role) which is the same user context (a virtual account created by the guest agent) as a startup task, which is different than the w3wp/asp.net (which runs as standard network user).

However, a better question might be - why is your PhantomJS process not still running?  If it is expected to shut down due to inactivity or something like that then simply restarting it may be ok.  But if it is shutting down for unknown reasons then you might consider treating the role as in an unknown healthy state and recycle the entire role.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer three suggestions.

1. Make sure PhantomJS doesn't die. From personal experience I know that can be really tough.
2. Package up and deploy an .exe that ensures that the PhantomJS process is always running. It can monitor running processes and if it notices the PhantomJS process is dead, it will restart it.
3. Create a special endpoint that allows you to restart the process remotely/on demand. This is the last option because of security issues. It's a possibility, but not recommended.